# Nested areas in MVC 2 / MVC 3 / MVC 4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

Since MVC 2 we can create areas easily. Now my question is related to nested areas (areas inside of areas).

Select my "`father`" area folder, Right-mouse-click > `Add` > NO option for a `new Area`.

Is it possible to do it in some other way ? or will this option be available in the near future?

Comment: I read this twice and thought Org structure for company intranet..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I realise this is an old question but I'll answer it in case anyone else is trying to figure it out. A solution to this is to create areas that use a different routing value at a lower level than area, so for example your RouteConfig would look something like this:

```
public class RouteConfig
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// A function that registers the default navigation route.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="routes">The RouteCollection to act on.</param>
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            var route = routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{area}/{subArea}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { area = "DefaultArea", controller = "Home", action = "Splash", id = UrlParameter.Optional, section = "Customer" },
            namespaces: new string[] { "Application.Controllers" });
        }
    }
```

And one of your sub-area registrations might look like this:

```
public class ApplicationSubAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
{
    public override string AreaName 
    {
        get 
        {
            return "ApplicationSubArea";
        }
    }

    public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
    {
        context.MapRoute(
            "SubArea_default",
            "Area/SubArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            new string[] { "Application.Areas.AreaName.SubAreaName.Controllers" }
        );
    }
}
```

After reading that, does "area" still look like a word? Because it doesn't to me.

P.S. You can do this recursively as many times as you like (theoretically) such that for example you could do

```
url: "{area}/{subArea}/{subSubArea}/{subSubSubArea}/{evenMoreSubArea}/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

in your RouteConfig.cs and

```
"Area/SubArea/SubSubArea/SubSubSubArea/EvenMoreSubArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
```

in your area registration.

Comment: You can even do complicated routing like "{area}/{subArea}/{controller}/{action}/{id}" and then "{area}/ExplicitSubArea/{controller}/{action}/{id}" such that anything with subArea = "ExplicitSubArea" would route to the specified set of controllers regardless of the area it's in, although this gets messy and in most cases probably isn't what you _should_ do.

Comment: Thanks for reopening this question and for such a nice solution. I still haven't tried it yet, but I will give this answer the correct choice. Thanks once again :)

Answer (score 3):

For now there isn't any information telling if there will be nested areas.

In the future maybe this will change.

Answer (score 2):

Using the idea of [Multi-project areas](http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/a-first-look-at-asp-net-mvc-2.aspx#multiproject-areas)  as a start, I guess you could recursively create more nested areas.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help. It's more like a study which is in mvc-contrib.
I saw it for version 1 don't know if it's compatible for MVC2
It's the concept of sub-controllers: http://mhinze.com/subcontrollers-in-aspnet-mvc/

Answer (score 0):

At this time *MVC supports only Main Application and then Areas in next level and NOT nested Areas*, but you can look at [This Nuget Package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcCodeRouting/1.0.2) that adds the following functionality to your project:

- Organize your controllers and views using namespaces (no more areas) that can go as deep as you want.
- Default constraints for primivite types that can be overridden on a per-parameter or per-site basis.
- Intelligent grouping of similar routes for efficient matching.
- Support for a root controller.
- Support for overloaded actions.
- Support for hierarchical (a.k.a. RESTful) routes.
- Support for user-defined custom routes.
- Detection of ambiguous routes.
- Formatting of routes (e.g. to lowercase, hyphen-separated, underscore-separated, etc).
- Render your routes as calls to the MapRoute extension method, for debugging.
- Support for embedded views (as assembly resources).

Answer (score -2):

You do not want to have nested aereas.
There is something wrong in your Software design.

the most common case is, that you use areas as Html Renderer,
therefore are the Display Templates.

Comment: No, that is not the reason, neither a problem with the design :) the idea of nested areas would be to have all the the pros from the "Areas" and extend them into a "tree type organization" as well - organization and separation of concepts into nested areas. That would be really cool. Just like some part of the "nested master-pages" concept.

Comment: An Master page is only the "View" part. that means, nesting them allows the view to have a hierarchy.
An Area has controller, Model, and View inside it. but okay, lets get deeper. how would you like to derive from the nested Area. in the controller? in the View call the other controller? maybe there is a design, that i just cant figure out...

Comment: An Area allows a different organization, not only because it has a different namespace, but also because it has his own directory structure of controllers, views, models. And I see a lot of advantages in this.

Comment: Yes, i completely agree on that. we encourage to use areas. but what is the reason to have them nested?

Comment: No need to nest the areas but you can produce an application that feels like it is hierarchical simply by creating a navigation scheme to facilitate this requirement. Use the xml site map and site map path to nest your controllers giving your site that hierarchical flow.

Comment: Multitenancy could be a use case for nested areas

Comment: Nested areas don't necessarily mean that there is something wrong with the design. In a large and complex application having a single level of areas would lead to route proliferation. It would be like saying "why do you need subfolders on your disk? Surely a single level of folders is enough"