# Areas inside Areas? MVC4

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, architecture

I am developing a big application, consisting of three main applications with many modules within each one.

All three share the same security and layouts. The division is fundamentally logical.

I'm looking for the best aproach in terms of organization.
Using the simple area structure is not enough as each area should have more areas inside to separate the modules.

Creating three separate projects raises problems with authentication and sharing resources as partial views.

I tried portable areas, but it complicates the development of changes for my team as they must be built to test any change even if it is only at a view.

Is there any other solution I can try? is there anything like Areas within Areas?

I really dont wanna have a thousan areas names App1.Admin, App2.Admin, App1.Dashboard...

Any advice is welcome. Thank you!

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3211663/nested-areas-in-mvc-2-mvc-3-mvc-4

Comment: Okay, that post is helpfull for the routing issue with subareas. but all the areas still in the same folder "Areas". So the problem with large applicationes still. I'd like to have areas folders inside an area or at list be able to divide areas in disctints folders.

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I managed to create new areas folders like (Areas, Areas1, Areas2) on the root of the application and register them in global.asax with the following code:

```
    private static void RegistrarAreaEntidades()
    {
        string[] newAreaStrings = new string
            [] { "~/Areas.Entidades/{2}/Views/{1}/{0}.cshtml" };
        var razorEngine = ViewEngines.Engines.OfType<RazorViewEngine>().First();
        razorEngine.AreaMasterLocationFormats =
            razorEngine.AreaMasterLocationFormats.Concat(newAreaStrings).ToArray();
        razorEngine.AreaViewLocationFormats =
            razorEngine.AreaViewLocationFormats.Concat(newAreaStrings).ToArray();
    }
```

Now the new areas work BUT Visual Studio don't recognize them. If I do Html.ActionLink("idksomething", "Index", "Home", new {area= "Example"}), VS underlines "Example" but the links works fine.
It seems like I have to register the area in another place.
¿Any ideas?

PD: Sorry for my bad English.